# Java, Move Rectangle Back and Forth

Tags: java

I'm trying to animate an object to move back and forth between two boundaries. For instance, once the x coordinate of the object reaches 500 it moves in the opposite direction to 200 and then moves back again until it reaches 500 and so on. However, the rectangle will only move to 500 and then stop. Here is a simplified version of my code:

```
public class Test
{

    public static class Game extends JComponent implements ActionListener
    {
        int width=100;
        int height=100;
        int x=300;
        int y=200;
        Timer timer;
        public Game()
        {
            timer = new Timer(20,this);
            timer.start();
        }
        public void paint(Graphics g)
        {
            g.drawRect(x,y,width,height);
            g.setColor(Color.red);
            g.fillRect(x,y,width,height);
        }
        public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e)
        {
            if(x>100)
            {
                x+=5;
            }
            if(x>500)
            {
                x-=5;
            }

            repaint();
        }
    }
    public static void main(String[] args)
    {
        JFrame frame = new JFrame("Test");
        frame.setPreferredSize(new Dimension(800,600));
        frame.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
        frame.add(new Game());
        frame.pack();
        frame.setVisible(true);
    }


}
```

Comment: `x > 100 AND > 500` .... ?

Comment: yea, I if I did less than 500, than the rectangle doesn't move

Comment: So if x is 505 it moves right 5 then left 5, essentially staying still. Is that what you want?

Comment: Note that this isn't just an issue of fixing the conditionals; there is no way to know from the x coordinate what direction the rectangle should be moving.

Comment: no, if the minimum boundary is 200 and the maximum is 500, then it should move back and forth between the minimum and maximum boundary. It's like a moving platform in a game.

Comment: @user1058860 I'm just saying that's what your code does right now.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Look at it this way, based on your logic, while `x` is greater than `100`, add `5`, while it's greater than `500` subtract `5`...

So once it reaches more than `500`, it's both greater than `100` AND greater than `500`...so you're going to add and subtract `5`, meaning it won't go anywhere.

What you need is a base `delta` value which describes the amount of change to apply.  You would then flip this value based on your ranges...

```
public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {

    x += delta;
    if (x > 500) {
        delta *= -1;
        x = 500;
    } else if (x < 100) {
        delta *= -1;
        x = 100;
    }

    repaint();
}
```

You may also want to have a look at [Performing Custom Painting](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/painting/) (as overriding `paint` isn't recommended and you should be calling `super.paint` so as not to break the paint chain) and [Initial Threads](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/concurrency/initial.html)

Answer (score 1):

You have a small logic error in your code.

```
if(x>100)
{
   x+=5;
}
if(x>500)
{
   x-=5;
}
```

If `x` is greater than 500 it is also greater than 100. Therefore, when it reaches 505 it will add 5 then subtract 5 each update. I suggest that you have a `movingRight` variable that you change based on `x`.

```
boolean movingRight = true; // start moving right

… // start of update method

if(movingRight)
{
   x+=5;
}
else
{
   x-=5;
}

if (x == 500) // turn around and go the other way
{
    movingRight = false;
}
else if (x == 200) // turn around and go the other way
{
    movingRight = true;
}

repaint();
```